# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Tags: php, post, if-statement

OK I'm returning to PHP after not using it for a couple of years and I'm trying to do a simple check of a $_POST variable.

I have:

```
if(isset($_POST['partydate'])) { $partydate = $_POST['partydate'] } else { $partydate = "No Date Selected" };
```

It's the only thing on that line but I keep getting the following when the page runs:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs....... on line 3
```

What is the obviously VERY simple thing I am overlooking here?!

Comment: I think you'd appreciate the conditional operator: `$partydate = isset($_POST['partydate']) ? $_POST['partydate'] : "No Date Selected";`

Comment: @SteAp, your edit actually fixes the bad code that is the point of the question, so answers don't make sense anymore.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for that. Did I really added the two ';' signs? Should I rewrite it to make it a one-liner again?

Comment: Yes! As @SirDarius says you've actually made a bad question even worse!

Comment: @DuckInCustard In your next post, please indent source-code. Without indentation, it is very hard to read.

Comment: OK, changed it back from even worse to worse. Please excuse! Can't understand, why newbies write non-indented code ;-)

Comment: Because as I commented against the accepted answer.. I do usually ALWAYS indent but was trying to keep a possible 60 or so lines down to a dozen. Hopefully this question / answer will help other "newbies" from making the same shortcut mistakes. - not sure why the question has received negative votes though? Surely its a valid question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liners are bad for code readability. If displayed better, your code becomes:

```
if (isset($_POST['partydate'])) {
    $partydate = $_POST['partydate']
}
else { 
    $partydate = "No Date Selected"
}
;
```

So as you can see, you are missing semi-colons in your if and else blocks. Proper code is:

```
if (isset($_POST['partydate'])) {
    $partydate = $_POST['partydate'];
}
else { 
    $partydate = "No Date Selected";
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!! I. Am. An. Idiot!! Was just trying to keep everything compact as I'm checking about 10 variables so didn't want to have 6 or so lines for each check. An in the process have made myself look a bit of a tit! Will make proper use of the ternary operator as suggested by a couple of others. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ternary `if` if you really want to use a one-liner:

```
$partydate = isset($_POST['partydate']) ? $_POST['partydate'] : "No Date Selected";
```

Comment: Thank you. Forgot about the ternary operator. Will do this thank you. Have accepted @SirDarius as the answer though as he actually explains what is wrong with my original code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for size, with proper placement of ";"

```
if(isset($_POST['partydate'])) { 
    $partydate = $_POST['partydate'];
} else { 
   $partydate = "No Date Selected";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have miss two

> ;

after the assignment of the string try this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['partydate'])) { 
      $partydate = $_POST['partydate']; 
} else { 
     $partydate = "No Date Selected"; 
};
```